# mvc 3 validation annotation error messages are not displayed next to the fields form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am new to mvc, what i have is a messaging class

```
[Table("employeeTable")]
public class Messsaging : IValidatableObject
{
    public virtual int id { set; get; }
    [Required]
    public virtual String name { set; get; }
    [Required]
    public virtual String country { set; get; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (name.Equals(null))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("this field can'not be empty");
        }
    }
}
```

and i have a Create action method

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Messsaging form)
    {
        var newmessage = messageContext.messages.Add(form);
        messageContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

when i submit the form i get an validation error exception message within the project instead of getting the error messages displayed on my creation form!! any ideas thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the `ModelState` before saving and if invalid, return the view

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Messsaging form)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(form); // returns the view with errors
  }
  // It OK so save
}
```

Comment: thank you very much Stephen!! it now works, my instructor did the code without the above if condition in the action method, but he is using mvc3 and i am using mvc4 , do you think this is what's propebly was causing the issue? 
thanks a lot Sir

Comment: AFAIK, there is no difference between MVC 3 and 4 relating to this

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to set the field name(s) in the ValidationResult constructor and use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() to check the value of the name property.

```
[Table("employeeTable")]
public class Messsaging : IValidatableObject
{
    public virtual int id { set; get; }
    [Required]
    public virtual String name { set; get; }
    [Required]
    public virtual String country { set; get; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("this field can'not be empty", new[] { "name" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Peter and thank you for your answer, the thing is that , even when i remove the custom validation method and stick with the built in once , i don't get any validation message displayed and instead i get an error thrown and pointing to the saveChanges(). line in the create action method

Comment: Open the InnerException-s and you will see what is the error but Stephen pointed out that you should use at least the ModelState for error checking.